# FEDEX API Oauth token - Missing or duplicate parameters. Please modify your request and try again. Javascript

Tags: javascript, request, fedex

The title says it all. I'm messing with the FEDEX API trying to get my token but it's not letting me. I have coded this in python and tried it in postman and both ways work fine, I'm new to JS and can't get it to work.

I get the error:

> [{"code":"BAD.REQUEST.ERROR","message":"Missing or duplicate parameters. Please modify your request and try again."}]

What's wrong? Did I possibly spell something wrong or is the formatting wrong?

```
var input = {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "*****",
  "client_secret": "*****"
}

var data = JSON.stringify(input)

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});


xhr.open("POST", "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I've had the most success using exactly the format FedEx shows in their [sample code](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html).

Specifically, I found that their sandbox has a problem with `input` UNLESS it is formatted EXACTLY how they show it formatted in the "Payload" tab in their [documentation](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/catalog/authorization/v1/docs.html).

---

For some reason...

#### THIS BREAKS:

```
var input = {
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": "*****",
  "client_secret": "*****"
}

var data = JSON.stringify(input)
```

and...

#### THIS WORKS:

```
var data = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*****&client_secret=*****');
```

Apparently, `JSON.stringify` and other serialization methods put the data in a slightly different order, different spacing, or SOMETHING that the FedEx sandbox will not recognize. This really shouldn't be an issue, but they really didn't make a robust sandbox.

---

### Here's what the full request should look like:

```
var data = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=*****&client_secret=*****');
  
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
  
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});
  
xhr.open("POST", "https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/oauth/token");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
```

> *Of course, replace the stars with your actual `client_id` and `client_secret`.*

I know it's a year late, but I hope this helps someone.